# Displaying PHP variables within Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am currently developing a stock market simulator and I am attempting to display the first generated price for each virtual company. To do this, I have generated my prices in PHP and added them to the array '$firstValue'. I have also generated IDs for my HTML elements in which these values will be displayed and these are stored in '$priceIdentifiers'. Below is the code used to generate the values:

**PHP:**

```
$priceIdentifiers = array("Prices1", "Prices2", "Prices3");
$normalDistChangers = array("-1000", "1000");
$highValues = array("2500", "4850", "1780");
$lowValues = array("2200", "4300", "1400");
$firstValue = array();

for ($x = 0, $length = 3; $x < $length; $x++)
{
  $tempValue = (rand($lowValues[$x], $highValues[$x]) / 100);
  $tempMean = log(($tempValue) / (rand($lowValues[$x], $highValues[$x]) / 100));
  $tempAnnStdDev = sqrt(365 * ($tempMean * $tempMean));
  $tempNormalDist = (rand($normalDistChangers[0], $normalDistChangers[1]) / 1000);
  $tempPrice = number_format(($tempValue * (1 + ($tempMean * (1/100000)) + $tempAnnStdDev * sqrt(1 / 100000) * $tempNormalDist)), 2, '.', '');

  array_push($firstValue, $tempPrice);
}
```

Below is the code for the HTML elements in which the prices will be displayed. As I am working with 3 companies at the moment, there are 3 rows generated.

**HTML and PHP:**

```
<td style = "text-align:center;font-size:15pt" id = "<?php echo $priceIdentifiers[$a]; ?>"></td>
```

Where $a is a variable equal to 0 and increments until its value is equal to 2.

Generating the values has worked and I have seen in the console log that, when displaying the contents of the list, the 3 prices for the different companies are in the list but when attempting to display them using the following Javascript code, it ends up displaying the whole array and not the individual element:

**Javascript:**

```
var tempPriceOne = <?php echo json_encode($firstValue); ?>;

var a = 0;
var highPrice = tempPriceOne;

var inv = setInterval(function() {
    if (a < 50)
      {
        document.getElementById("Prices1").innerHTML = tempPriceOne;
```

At the moment, when looking on the website: http://leonid.chashchin.net/stockMarket.php , it displays the whole array in the first 'Price' row. What do I need to modify so that the first element is displayed in the first row, the second in the second and so on?

Comment: the tempPriceOne is an array of strings. From view source: var tempPriceOne = ["24.24","47.25","15.21"];

Comment: Welcome. `$firstValue` is an array. What exactly do you expect the value of that cell to be?

Comment: @Nawed Khan yes that is correct. What I am struggling with at the moment is displaying each element in that list individually as the rows go down and the element in priceIdentifiers increments.

Comment: @Jeto I have researched other posts about implementing PHP array elements into Javascript and have tried to use the json_encode method. I had hoped that it would display each element in the list individually but, however, this did not work.

Comment: @LeoChashchin What you did does put the array into a JS variable, and is the proper way to do it. Your issue is that you're not looping over the array (on JS side), but instead outputting it "as is" into a cell expecting a single (string) value.

Comment: @Jeto I understand now thank you. I was just confused with what a json_encode did when I decided to display it and I was not too sure. Thankfully, I've now got a solution to how to solve the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing/assigning the whole array and not just the individual elements.

This is how you would print individual elements:

```
document.getElementById("Prices1").innerHTML = tempPriceOne[0];
document.getElementById("Prices2").innerHTML = tempPriceOne[1];
document.getElementById("Prices3").innerHTML = tempPriceOne[2];
```

Comment: This pretty much did the job for me. Quite surprised that I didn't see this as a solution but was just confused with being able to understand exactly what json_encode actually did. Thank you very much for your response.